# Woocommerce - find product variations without regular price set?

Tags: woocommerce

I have a bug with a Woocommerce website where by *sometimes* when saving the product, the regular price for all variations gets removed. This then causes a message to the customer saying that the product cannot be added to their cart when they try to buy.

Whilst I try and track down the bug, does anyone know how I may try to find all the product variations where the regular price is not set?

Answer (score 0):

I could run a regular post query. I think the following parameters fit your description, but I have not tested it.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product_variation',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => '_regular_price',
            'value'   => '',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),
);
$variations = new WP_Query( $args );
```

In trying to debug your issue, I'd take a look at any plugins hooking in to `woocommerce_save_product_variation` or similar.